# Can we use nltk decision tree/SVM/random forest to train data with text or list of string as feature?

Tags: nltk, text-classification

Is it possible to train data with text / string / list of strings features with algorithm other than naive Bayes? I referred gender classification problem given in http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html
It is done with naive Bayes. Can we do same with other algorithms from nltk library?

Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import nltk
import random
q = open('question.txt').read()
i = open('notquestion.txt').read()
labeled_sentence = ([(name, 1) for name in sent_tokenize(q)] +[(name, 0) for name in sent_tokenize(i)])
random.shuffle(labeled_sentence)
df = pd.DataFrame(labeled_sentence, columns=['sentence','label'])
trainingSet, testSet = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), tokenizer=df['sentence'].values.astype('str').tolist(),
               min_df=3, max_df=0.9, strip_accents='unicode', use_idf=1,
               smooth_idf=1, sublinear_tf=1 )
x = vec.fit_transform(df['sentence'].values.astype('str'))

#naiveBayers equation
def pr(y_i, y):
    p = x[y==y_i].sum(0)
    return (p+1) / ((y==y_i).sum()+1)

#SVM and logistic regression is more or less the same.
def logistic_regression(y):
    y = y.values
    naive = np.log(pr(1,y) / pr(0,y))
    model = LogisticRegression(C=4, dual=True)
    x_nb = x.multiply(naive)
    return model.fit(x_nb, y), naive
```

Comment: Yes. nltk library has SVM. But quick check says nltk svm library is been using scikitlearn class functions either way. Why you want to concentrate on only nltk libraries?

Comment: Ok .That means using sklearn naive Bayes, decision tree,SVM is same as using algorithms from nltk, Isn't it ??Is it necessary to convert string,list of string to numeric vectors like bag of word model to train with classifier?

Comment: Yes. Depends on your text data. Is it a sentence of text to get classified or categories of text? What does your text data look like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238091/is-it-correct-to-use-pos-tag-as-feature-in-questions-identification.  This is what I wanted to do.I'm able to use nltk naive Bayes classifier .How to implement other classifiers?Is it possible to use directly other classifiers without converting features into vectors

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The question was ambiguous and now its clear. So Naive Bayes is commonly used along with tf-idf and regression technique. So you can use the below code to get better accuracy in your classifier and make better predictions. Yes all text inputs should be converted into numerical values as tf-df or one-hot encoding or word vectors embedding. 
Have sentences as a list of sentences from your file.

```
from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
toktok = ToktokTokenizer()
tokenized_sentences = [toktok.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences] 

vec = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), tokenizer=tokenized_sentences,
               min_df=3, max_df=0.9, strip_accents='unicode', use_idf=1,
               smooth_idf=1, sublinear_tf=1 )
x = vec.fit_transform(sentences)

#naiveBayers equation
def pr(y_i, y):
    p = x[y==y_i].sum(0)
    return (p+1) / ((y==y_i).sum()+1)

#SVM and logistic regression is more or less the same.
def logistic_regression(y):
    y = y.values
    naive = np.log(pr(1,y) / pr(0,y))
    model = LogisticRegression(C=4, dual=True)
    x_nb = x.multiply(naive)
    return model.fit(x_nb, y), naive
```

train data containing questions labeled as 1 or 0 and answers labelled 1 or 0. Load your two text files into pandas for each line in text file and create a additional column with a label. Test data should have gone through tf-idf as well similarly.

```
model,naive = logistic_regression(train_data)  
pred = model.predict_proba(test_data.multiply(naive))
```

Courtesy: Jeremy Howard lectures and notebooks

Comment: I have included code in question..I'm not getting how you are extracting features and those pr and logistic_regression functions.